# How to pass the custom variables from ResetPasswordController to reset blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

How to pass the custom variables from ResetPasswordController to reset blade template.

ResetPasswordController.php

```
 public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
 {
    $data = array(
        'title'=>'Reset password',
        'description'=> 'Reset password to abc.com',
        'seo_keywords'=> 'Reset password to abc.com',
      );
      return view('auth/password/reset',$data);

 }
```

Comment: You're already passing data to the view. What is the problem here?

Comment: data is not passing actually...all three title,description, seo_keywords is null

Comment: From your blade catch data like this `{{ $data->title  }}`

Comment: Can you the code where you are trying to access the variables in your view to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning a `view()`, the second argument can be used to pass variables to the blade template (just like you have done)

```
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('auth/password/reset',[
        'title'         =>'Reset password',
        'description'   => 'Reset password to abc.com',
        'seo_keywords'  => 'Reset password to abc.com',
    ]);
}
```

These would then be accessable as `{{ $title }}`, `{{ $description}}`, `{{ $seo_keywords}}`.

If you are unable to retrieve these, it may be because you are editting the wrong blade template. The default template is located at `auth.passwords.reset` (`resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php`).

I'd suggest just adding a `{{ dd('here) }}` at the top of that template to make sure it is in fact the template being used by your application!

Comment: thanks! how can do the same for Forgotpasswordcontroller I am not able to find the showResetForm function...

Comment: The default view is inherited from the `SendsPasswordResetEmails` trait. You can overide this by adding a `showLinkRequestForm()` function to your `ForgotPasswordController`. it is using `'auth.passwords.email'` as the default template